# Is it possible to change the point size of text in the middle of a string with imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to do a "BIGsmall" sort of thing in my image where "BIG" is in a larger point size and then "small" continues in a smaller point size.

Normally I'd do it in two passes with different point sizes for each one, but I don't know the width of the "BIG" part ahead of time, so I wouldn't know where the "small" part should begin.

I suppose I could render "BIG" to a separate image and then check it's width.. but I'm hoping there's an easier solution. Does one exist?

The entire text should all fit on a single line if that makes a difference.

Comment: The [pango:](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#pango) protocol is the best way to manage this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33127002/2836621 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/33121278/2836621

Comment: Thanks! (I did try searching for similar questions first, but apparently didn't use the right terms...) I think pango will do the trick.